# Classical physics problems involving the ODE $dx/dt + tx = 0$

Tags: classical-mechanics, fourier-transform, differential-equations

I’m teaching a course on oscillations, waves and Fourier analysis. The best way I know to show the Fourier invariance of the Gaussian $\exp(-t^2/2)$ (which is both of fundamental mathematical importance<sup>[1](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183547543),[2](https://books.google.fr/books?id=5rcqrJT9gAgC&lpg=PA29&vq=recurring&pg=PA29)</sup> and useful for illustration of wave packets) is to observe that it is the unique solution of the (non-autonomous!) equation
$$
  \frac{dx}{dt} + tx = 0,
$$
which is itself Fourier-invariant.

I’d rather have an independent motivation from physics to introduce this equation than pull it out of the hat as a formal trick. It is, of course, the equation for the ground state of the quantum harmonic oscillator (with $x$ the wave function and $t$ the space coordinate), but that comes much later in the course. So, can you think of a reasonable situation in *classical* physics (preferably mechanics) that involves it?

<sup>I’d agree this were too vague if I could think of at least *one*, but I can’t.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

In a [convection diffusion equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convection%E2%80%93diffusion_equation), particles trying to diffuse outwards (perfume molecules in air) while moving along a given velocity field (air moving). The equation given on wikipedia is, with $c$ being t he concentration:

$$\partial_t c=\partial_x(D \partial_x c)-\partial_x(vc)+R$$
take $R=0$, $\partial_t c=0$, to get $$0=\partial_x(D \partial_x c-v c)$$

Ignoring the constant of integration (solutions of $D \partial_x c-v c=a$ don't go to zero at infinity), we're left with your equation. Take $D=1$ and $v=-x$.

$$\partial_x c+x c=0$$

This is the steady state equation for perfume molecules diffusing outwards while a weird breeze pushes them towards the origin.

I think it's going to be difficult to find something not based on some kind of drift, diffusion, or thermodynamic equation!

Comment: It has to be some sort of PDE in disguise to be non-autonomous, doesn’t it?.. :-/ I’m a bit wary of this “weird breeze” though because I don’t see if it itself satisfies mass or momentum conservation (for the “air”).

Comment: @AlexShpilkin It wouldn't satisfy mass conservation (there would have to be sinks of air everywhere). It could probably also be interpreted as charged particles in a potential subject to a random force, but I would have to go through a derivation.